# FFT transform length in FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fft, fpga

Dear  I am using xilinx FFT IP cores for FFT transformation but the problem is that FFT IP core takes fixed transformations length of 64,128,256,512,...
is it possible to use transform length of 50 , 100 , 126 etc. ie other than the available transform length of the iP core

is there any other solution to implement FFT for variety of transform lengths

Haider

Answer (score 4):

Generally FFTs are implemented in hardware using a particular architecture called a butterfly.  This architecture only works for power of 2 block sizes.  It is possible to do arbitrary length FFTs, but the implementation is more complicated.  Generally the solution when you need a non-power-of-2 size FFT is to zero pad to the closest power of 2 size.  So if you need 50 points, pad it to 64 points with zeros.